# Smooth content transition on interrupt current transition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a menu where I can click navigation links. I change some content by using jquery `fadeOut`, `fadeIn`

**Primary: OnClick**

```
Link1 | Link2 | Link3

Content 1 | Content 2 | Content 3
```

Every links hides all content elements and fade in the specified content element.
 The problem is here: 
**The user click very fast on link1, link2 than on link3. 
The content elements are not fully faded out or a other content element is fading in.**

I can use stop, but these will be not smooth at all. It should continue to fadeout while the fadeout is interrupted and fadein should fadeout, so everything appear smooth. Is there a elegant way.

Here is the function how i solved the fading right now.

```
function showContent(contentId) {
   $(".content-elements").stop(true, true);
   return $when($(".content-elements").fadeOut(800)).then($(contentId).fadeIn(800));
}
```

**UPDATE: Here is a little Sandbox [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RLDQF/2/)**

---

**Optional: MouseOver**

```
|BOX1|BOX2|BOX3|
Content 1 | Content 2 | Content 3
```

Additional i like to have a small timeout before navigating to prevent transtion if the user enter a box accidentally. So the fadeOut of the current element should wait until 2 seconds gone and can fadein the element where the mouse currently is.

Comment: It is not clear what you want the behavior to be when the user clicks before the existing fade is done.

Comment: It should continue to fadeout while the fadeout is interrupted and fadein should fadeout, so everything appear smooth.

Comment: How can it continue to fadeout when the fadeout is interrupted?  Don't understand.  Do you want the current operation to finish before the next operation is started?  That would queue the next operation and NOT interrupt the current operation, but also leads to a build-up of queued operations if the user clicks fast.  Usually, once the user has expressed a different interest than what is currently running, you want to just ignore the old operation and switch to what the user most recently requested (which is what `.stop()` is good for.

Comment: @jfriend00 i can use fadeTo to continue the fadeout. The fadein should never start. If i interrupt on fadein it should fadeout from the current opacity state.

Comment: The use `.stop(true, false)` and `.fadeTo()`.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. That's why i ask.

Comment: Please don't use the topic title to indicate the status of the question. It will be marked as so when an answer has been accepted.

Comment: Your jsFiddle leaves me more confused as to what you want help with.  You have no answers because it is still not clear what you want help with.  There are no click handlers in the jsFiddle and your random time interval occurs before the previous animation is done.  What do you want the desired behavior to be?

Comment: doesn't matter, takes to long to figure it out. will stuck the animations. http://jsfiddle.net/RLDQF/4/